# How can I add a row to a table in Javascript without it immediately resetting?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript, but I'm struggling with a very simple example.

I have a form and I want to add its contents to a new table row in "catalog" every time the user hits submit.

But when I hit submit using the code below, I see the new table row flash briefly and then disappear, as if the page is being reset.

When I use the commented out code instead (just appending the form contents to body.innerHTML), it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4   /loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript test</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addItem() {
    var itemName = document.getElementById('item_name').value;      
    var itemPrice = document.getElementById('item_price').value;

    var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
    //var body = document.getElementById('body');
   //body.innerHTML += itemName;    
   newRow.innerHTML = "<td>" + itemName + "</td><td>" + itemPrice + "</td>";
   var catalog = document.getElementById('catalog');
   catalog.appendChild(newRow);
}

</script>

<body id="body"> 
 <form><h2>Add an Item to the Catalog</h2>

<p>Item Name: <input type="text" id="item_name" value="" /> Price: <input type="text"    id="item_price" value="" /></p>

<input type="submit" onClick="addItem()" value="Add" id="submit" />
<input type="reset" id="reset" />
</form>

<table id="catalog"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input type of 'submit' will submit the form after executing your JavaScript.

If you change the input type to 'button' you will see your code working.

```
<input type="button" onClick="addItem()" value="Add" id="submit" />
```

This is also known as a 'PostBack' which involves taking the data in input fields on a form, and posting it to the page again. The data that is posted to the page can be picked up from server-side code as a basis for some further action.

Otherwise, your code is fine. My only suggestion would be to construct `td`s in the same way as you are constructing the `tr`s

Comment: Thanks for the extremely fast answer, its working as I expected now.

Answer (score 0):

Change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`